# table not rendering rows ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Does anyone know why the page is not rendering the rows in table?

Here is my code:

```
private void loadPhotos(DataTable dtPhotos)
        {
            int rowNumber = 0;
            foreach (DataRow row in dtPhotos.Rows) 
            {
                if (tblPhotosAfter.Rows[rowNumber].Cells.Count == 4)
                {
                    TableRow newRow = new TableRow();
                    TableCell newCell = new TableCell();
                    Image img = new Image();
                    img.ImageUrl = row["ImageName"].ToString();
                    img.Width = img.Height = 200;
                    newCell.Controls.Add(img);
                    newRow.Cells.Add(newCell);
                    tblPhotosAfter.Rows.Add(newRow);
                    rowNumber++;
                }
                else {
                    TableCell newCell = new TableCell();
                    Image img = new Image();
                    img.ImageUrl = row["ImageName"].ToString();
                    img.Width = img.Height = 200;
                    newCell.Controls.Add(img);
                    tblPhotosAfter.Rows[rowNumber].Cells.Add(newCell);
                }
            }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
                        <asp:Table CssClass="table table-hover" runat="server" ID="tblPhotosAfter" >
                            <asp:TableRow>
                            </asp:TableRow> 
                        </asp:Table>
                    </div>
```

Debugging the code, the table has all the rows and cells, but in the page does not appear

Thanks

Edited in from comments:

calling the method loadPhotos:

```
 var dtPhotos = dataManager.DataTableQuery(sConn,query);
 if (dtPhotos.Rows.Count > 0) { loadPhotos(dtPhotos); }
```

Edit:
Im calling the method in button event btnSearchEcoNumber, also i have a scriptManager

```
asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUploadSign" />
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearchEcoNumber" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: How is this tagged as both asp.net and winforms?   Two completely independant presentation frameworks.

Comment: sorry, i changed it, its webforms

Comment: check css of classes "table" and "table-hover". Maybe one of them has display: none property?

Comment: When is the `loadPhotos` method called? During pageLoad?

Comment: the CSS looks like bootstrap, I don't think it's causing a problem

Comment: @GermanOrtiz shoot I should have seen that..!!

Comment: Please show where loadPhotos is called in your code. Possibly related to postback?

Comment: calling the method loadPhotos
var dtPhotos = dataManager.DataTableQuery(sConn,query);
                if (dtPhotos.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    loadPhotos(dtPhotos);
                    
                }

Comment: Please add that comment as formatted code in OP. Also, you're not telling us **where** you're calling it from. Is it in Page_Load or some other method?

Comment: OP - Your code looks ok to me, I suspect that what is happening is that somewhere after you are calling this code, something else is re-initialising the table.

It might be useful if you update your question to include the rendered HTML as well as the aspx markup so that we can see what is being outputted by the framework.

Comment: i addded where its calling the method loadPhotos

Comment: Ahh OK, by any chance in you Page_Onload() do you do anything to the table?

If so is that code wrapped in a if (!isPostback) ?

Comment: in my Page_Load just have if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                createDTMaterials();
                Session.Add("dtMaterials", dtMaterials);
            }
Page_Onload its empty

Comment: Is tblPhotosAfter inside of your UpdatePanel? As a test, you might try using the page without the UpdatePanel to check if the logic is working using the classic WebForms page cycle.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that imageUrl is correct.
I suggest you to add a label and write something in text property to test your code.